# Is there a more elegant way to "fake" class inheritance?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, prototype, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have not found an easy way to extend Mongoose Schema/Model methods because of the way that mongoose handles them, and because of the fact that `mongoose=require('mongoose')` is a singelton.

So, I am 'faking' class inheritance here:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function(MongooseModel, options) {
    var Collection = {};

    _.assign(Collection, _.toPlainObject(MongooseModel));

    Collection.pluralName = Collection.modelName + 's';
    Collection.foo = Collection.bar;

    return Collection

};
```

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

**EDIT:**

Turns out the above solution doesn't work.  For instance, using `Collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {...})` will error when Mongo tries to create "docs" from a model that has not been registered with Mongoose.

So, what I've done is now completely inelegant:

'use strict';

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function(MongooseModel, options) {

    var Collection = MongooseModel;

    ...

    return Collection

};
```

Comment: I don't think this is unelegant. You are simply using it as a Mixin, which is Composition. It looks fine to me, because there is less dependency between your object and the MongooseModel.

Comment: If it bothers you, you may consider creating a Factory Method and moving this _.assign logic up there. Then use this Factory Method just as you would use a constructor.

Comment: Just to shed some light on why I think this looks fine, Eric Elliot has articles and talks about this subject: http://ericleads.com/2013/06/classical-inheritance-is-obsolete-how-to-think-in-prototypal-oo/ and https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a#.sq5r9ln5f

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but instead of `_.assign` can't you do: `Collection = Object.create(MogooseModel);`?

Comment: In ES6 you can do this way: ```let Collection = Object.assign(Object.create(MongooseModel), { ... });```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to try and do this, though not sure exactly what your trying to extend.

You can add instance methods `<schema>.methods.<mymethod> = function(){}`

```
// define a schema
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

And you can add static methods `<schema>.statics.<mymethod> = function(){}`

```
// assign a function to the "statics" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
    return this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
}

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
Animal.findByName('fido', function (err, animals) {
    console.log(animals);
});
```

Examples are from the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) - just search for "statics".

The statics functions you can call on a model. The methods are usually functions that work with an instance of a document returned from a query or created with `new`.